# Returning Null results

Tags: php, sql-server

i have a database with several columns and one column is price.  For statistical purposes I would like to see the highest price an item was sold and the lowest price the item was sold at.  At the same time in case the item did not sell then i have another column which has the valuation of my product and would like to put that as the min and max price.  But my query only returns the min and max values but not the zero sales.  I know its due to the way my query is written

```
SELECT country,
       garden.gardenname,
       MIN(holdingcat.col11) AS minp,
       MAX(holdingcat.col11) AS maxp,
       brokers.brk_abv AS broker 
FROM holdingcat
     INNER JOIN garden ON holdingcat.col3 = garden.gardenid
     INNER JOIN producers ON holdingcat.col2 = producers.producerid
     INNER JOIN brokers ON holdingcat.broker = brokers.brk_id
     INNER JOIN grades On holdingcat.col4=gradeid 
WHERE gradename LIKE 'BP1'
  AND country = 'KENYA'
  AND (producercode = 'KTDA')
  AND (brk_abv = 'VENS' OR brk_abv ='ATBL')
  AND holdingcat.col11 > 0
  AND saleyear = 2018
  AND saleno BETWEEN 9 AND 9 
GROUP BY country,
         garden.gardenname,
         brokers.brk_abv 
ORDER BY garden.gardenname;
```

Can someone assist me in sorting the sql statement so that i can have the values where col11=0 are also captured coz if i put col11=0 the minimum price and max price is zero which will not be a true picture

Comment: First things first, don't use implicit joins, use actual `JOIN` syntax (it's been around for decades). Then, because you're using `JOIN` syntax, you can then use a `LEFT JOIN`. At the moment your implicit joins are also an `INNER JOIN`, meaning that if there is no relevant data in the related table, no rows will be returned.

Comment: That col11>0 will be a problem is you want col11=0

Comment: Am still new on this how would i use the Left Join in this example

Comment: `JOIN` syntax is well documented: [Joins (SQL Server)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins).  `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is covered under [Null Values and Joins](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins#nulls_joins). I'd suggest having a read/look first, as you'll learn a lot more by researching, trying and understanding yourself, rather than having a stranger on the internet do the work for you. if you get stuck, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49728659/edit) your post with what you've tried and comment back. :)

Comment: @paparazzo If i use col11=0 then if i have three similar products and one was sold and another was not sold then the minimum price will be zero which should not be the case

Comment: The minimum of 0 and a number bigger than 0 is 0.

Comment: @Larnu i have used the joins and edited the code

Comment: Thanks, but please remember to format your code. No one wants to see a `FROM` clause with 4 `INNER JOIN`s on a single line. It makes your entire SQL eligible. There's also no need for the `DISTINCT` and you're already doing a `GROUP BY`; the use of it will just slow the query down.

Comment: @Larnu well noted

Comment: so my question still remains how do i get items which have not been sold that is which have a price of zero coz if i use col11=0 my min price will always be zero and want to see if the item is ever sold what was the lowest price so as to guide a sales person